# Inputting a character value into an int array?

Tags: c++

This is the program that I wrote:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int hex[16];
        cout << "enter the 16 hexadecimal numbers\n";
        for(int i = 0;i < 16;i++)
        {
            cin >> hex[i];
            cout << "input worked\n";
        }
    }
```

[image]

Can you please explain to me why the "input worked" output is again being displayed after I inputted 'a'.
Shouldn't the program stop if I did that?

What I mean is why does  "input worked" line output after cin stopped taking input?I mean if there is a problem in taking input from cin why is cout still working?

Comment: The character `a` is not an `int` and you are trying to extract an `int`. This creates an *error* in the input `cin` and it stops working.

Answer (score 2):

You must pipe it through std::hex, otherwise it accepts just an integer and your input stream switches internally to an error state and the inputs of the next iteration are skipped. That's why you see the outputs of the remaining iterations.

```
cin >> std::hex >> hex[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
if(cin >> hex >> hex[i]) {
    cout << "input worked\n";
}
else {
    string dummy;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> dummy;
}
```

to determine if *input worked*. For the `hex` IO manipulator you must `#include <iomanip>`.

Comment: yeah but why do I get the  "input worked" line after cin stopped taking input?That is my main question

Comment: @Galik oh okay so the cin just stops from taking bad input but the for loop still works .Thats why cout is working right?

Comment: @user2546419 yes, after an error `cin` just returns immediately without doing anything.

Comment: @Galik: It's not an infinite loop because it terminates anyway after 16 iterations.

Comment: @Galik THX for pointing out. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

By default input streams like `std::cin` expect *integer* input to be in *decimal* (characters `'0'`-`'9'`). If you want to input in *hexadecimal* you need to use `std::hex`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hex[16];
    cout << "enter the 16 hexadecimal numbers\n";
    for(int i = 0;i < 16;i++)
    {
        // hexedicimal
        cin >> std::hex >> hex[i];
        cout << "input worked\n";
    }
}
```

Also you should always check the stream for errors after reading from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hex[16];
    cout << "enter the 16 hexadecimal numbers\n";
    for(int i = 0;i < 16;i++)
    {
        if(cin >> std::hex >> hex[i])
            cout << "input worked\n";
        else
        {
            cout << "bad input try again\n";
            cin.clear(); // remove the error
            std::string skip;
            cin >> skip; // read past bad input
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you named your array `hex` does not matter to the compiler. It expects decimal input.

When you enter `a`, the input cannot be parsed as a decimal integer, so `std::cin` is set to an error mode. The subsequent call to `>>` then no longer prompts the user for text input but immediately returns, leaving the stream in its error state, until the loop finishes.

You can solve this problem in several ways:

- Check the stream's state after the user has entered something. `if (!cin) { /* error handling */ }`.
- Additionally, allow hexadecimal input with [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex).

Or use a different strategy altogether. Instead of reading `int`s directly, each loop iteration could read a whole *line* of input into an `std::string`. That string can then be converted to an `int` with C++11's [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), specifying base 16:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int hex[16];
    std::cout << "enter the 16 hexadecimal numbers\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        try
        {
            hex[i] = std::stoi(line, 0, 16);
            std::cout << "input worked: " << hex[i] << "\n";
        }
        catch (std::exception const& exc)
        {
            std::cout << "input failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```